# "get_bind" receive no mapper when count using RoutingSession

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bind

I am using master/slave of sqlalchemy, by RoutingSession like

```
engines = {
    'master':create_engine("sqlite:///master.db"),
    'other':create_engine("sqlite:///other.db"),
    'slave1':create_engine("sqlite:///slave1.db"),
    'slave2':create_engine("sqlite:///slave2.db"),
}

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker
import random

class RoutingSession(Session):
    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        if mapper and issubclass(mapper.class_, MyOtherClass):
            return engines['other']
        elif self._flushing:
            return engines['master']
        else:
            return engines[
                random.choice(['slave1','slave2'])
            ]
```

[here the link:](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/files/2012/sqlalchemy_multiple_dbs.py)
the session:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession))

s = Session()
```

when i need a sun of data on Model3:

```
s.query(Model3).count()
```

sqlalchemy raise an error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: model3
```

Some one, please help how to accomplish this query.
Thank's in advanced.

Comment: i think you're confused; this only works if you have an existing replication setup.  it's not an implementation of replication; it's just a way to take advantage of it with SQLA.  also, you can't replicate sqlite.  so you're getting the error because your tables don't exist in the slave databases.

Comment: @Eevee but the sample code using sqlite?

Comment: yes, and the sample code doesn't work, because you can't replicate sqlite  :)

Comment: Is there a way, so the sample code can work?

Comment: no.  the sample code is a way to interface with a database feature that does not exist in sqlite.

Comment: @Eevee, thanks so much.  So, i can not use RoutingSession for multiple database.  It's right?

Comment: this only works if you have replication **already set up** between your multiple databases.  if you don't know what that means, then no, you can't use it.  why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: I use no replication, just sqlite.
I try used RoutingSession, may be this way more simple then using binds clause.  So, i decide just use a binds clause when constructs a session.
Thanks so much, @Eevee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the above technique is not applicable to sqlite; because sqlite cannot make a replication.